# Some numerically divergent sum

Tags: calculus-and-analysis

I try to get a numerically evaluation of the following sum:

$$\sum _{j=0}^{\infty } \frac{j^2}{\sqrt{j \left(j^2+\frac{1}{2}\right)}}$$

using different methods. With Euler-Maclaurin we get

```
NSum[
j^2/Sqrt[j (j^2 + 1/2)]
, {j, 1, \[Infinity]}
, Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"
, WorkingPrecision ->  20]
```

with Levin u-transform we get the same result: Infinity

I think the correct sum is $$-0.78403507353706181$$  maybe it is part of some analytic continuation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by noticing that the $j=0$ term is zero,

```
Limit[j^2/Sqrt[j (1/2 + j^2)], j -> 0]
(*    0    *)
```

so we can sum from $j=1$. Then extract the dominant singular term $\sqrt{j}$ from the sum,

```
Asymptotic[j^2/Sqrt[j (1/2 + j^2)], j -> ∞]
(*    Sqrt[j]    *)
```

for easier numerical convergence through analytic continuation:

$$
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\frac{j^2}{\sqrt{j\left(j^2+\frac12\right)}}
= \sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\sqrt{j} +
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{j^2}{\sqrt{j\left(j^2+\frac12\right)}}-\sqrt{j}\right)\\
= \zeta\left(-\frac12\right) +
\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\left(\frac{j^2}{\sqrt{j\left(j^2+\frac12\right)}}-\sqrt{j}\right)
$$

```
Zeta[-1/2] + NSum[j^2/Sqrt[j (1/2 + j^2)] - Sqrt[j],
                  {j, 1, ∞}, 
                  Method -> "EulerMaclaurin"] // Chop
(*    -0.783497    *)
```

By playing with `NSum`'s parameters you may get more accurate values.

Comment: It should be noticed  that `Sum[Sqrt[j], {j, 1, Infinity}, Regularization -> "Dirichlet"]` performs `Zeta[-(1/2)]`.